# What is the difference between array([array([]),array([])]) and array([[],[]])?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

What is the difference between these two numpy arrays?

```
array([array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6])])
```

and

```
array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

How can we convert one to other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is the **same**. There's no need to convert anything:

```
A = np.array([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])])
B = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

assert np.array_equal(A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

The result would be the same, but the standard would normally be:

```
array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

Comment: How is this the standard way?

Comment: You come across this more often, more recognisable, if you will

Comment: That doesn't make it a standard.

Comment: I'm not specifically saying that it's a standard in that sense, I'm stating that you're more likely to come across this version than the other

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy-array)

> `numpy.array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)`
>
> **Parameters:** `object : array_like`
>
> - An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose
>     **array** method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence.

This means using:

```
array([array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6])])
```

Is just redundant to:

```
array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

As Numpy accepts nested lists *(arrays)* and will handle them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

These are just equivalent ways to create an array.

From the doc to  [np.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

```
numpy.array(object, ...

object : array_like

    An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose __array__ method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence
```

What you passed are both correct ways to initialize an array. Your first option is a nested sequence, the second one is a nested list.

.